Django Jenkins pipeline using wsl
I have a silly question, can we make a CI/CD pipeline for a django project using Jenkins and I don't have any access to cloud portals, can I do it using wsl
Till now I have not seen any article or video doing this, is it possible.?
I don't have any idea as I want to learn this thing
